# The disaster we worried about "most" or "the most"?

Tags: grammar, comparatives

I heard a Ted talk say

> When I was a kid, the disaster we worried about most was a nuclear
> war.

I wonder why it was not "the disaster we worried about THE most"?

Comment: Actually both forms are used: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=worry+about+most+is%2C+worry+about+the+most+is&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cworry%20about%20most%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cworry%20about%20the%20most%20is%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say either "the disaster we worried about most was a nuclear war" or "the disaster we worried about the most was a nuclear war". **Both are acceptable.**

Using "most" by itself means it's more worrisome more than other disasters, but leaves it open to the possibility that there might be a more worrisome disaster that just wasn't thought of.

Using "the most" implies that it is the absolute number one worst disaster possible.